# Is Skiko right now only available for JVM awt?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, skija, skiko

Using this: https://github.com/JetBrains/skiko/

I was able to get the SkiaAwtSample to work and it shows a window with a grid of animating clocks. It shows that the backend is OpenGL (I'm using Linux Mint 21, and have NVidia proprietary drivers installed). My first impression is that the performance seems average at best. I predict if I'd try to replicate this using plain old Java2D, I'd get similar performance. I also predict that the performance of Java2D is downplayed. But it is not performance that I am after.

I want to stop investing in UI and graphics technologies that aren't portable.

The samples directory shows these 4 subdirectories:
SkiaAndroidSample  SkiaAwtSample  SkiaJsSample  SkiaMultiplatformSample

When I try to use the build target in the SkiaJsSample directory, I get a long maven error report, that amounts to a dependency not having been met. It wants org.jetbrains.skiko:skiko:0.0.0-SNAPSHOT with 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'js'.

The DEVELOPMENT.md file only mentions of building and making available in the local maven repo using :skiko:publishToMavenLocal

Digging further, I tried :skiko-js-wasm-runtime:publicToMavenLocal but no such target exists.

It seems only the awt stuff is included in the github repository. Isn't the whole thing open source. I can find wasm related entries in online maven repos, but why can't we build it locally and public to our local maven repos?

Answer (score 1):

No, skiko can build for awt, js and ios. Try to use another project from the 'samples' folder, `SkiaMultiplatformSample`.

This example even has its own ReadMe. [Check it](https://github.com/JetBrains/skiko/tree/master/samples/SkiaMultiplatformSample)

Comment: I found an easy way to get access to Skia's drawing internals. You can create a canvas inside a Kotlin Compose project. The IDE takes care of the whole thing, and it doesn't take much code to create a basic project. Plus you get all that UI stuff that comes with it.